# Tensorflow freeze shuffled dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

For training model I am using shuffled dataset which was created so:

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

but after training I want to check the prediction results with some simple test function

```
def detect_wrong_ts(model,ds,label_encoder):
    # Take first elements batch 
    ds = ds.take(1)
    # Do data preprocessing 
    # it converts strings from initial dataset to indexes "word1 word2" -> [ 1, 2 ]
    mapper = lambda in1,in2,out : (model.preprocessor(in1),out)
    train = ds.map(mapper)
    
    # Do predictions on postprocessed dataset
    x = model.predict(train)

    # Now I try to print results with the information based 
    # on the 
    # 1 ) initial dataset 
    # 2 ) postprocessed dataset 
    # 3 ) prediction
    for batch,outp in zip(ds,train):
        inp = batch[0]
        outp_code = outp[0]
        for i,inp in enumerate(inp):
            inp_str = inp.numpy().decode("utf-8")
            inp_codes = model.preprocessor([inp_str])[0].numpy()
            postprocess_codes = outp_code[i].numpy()
            print(
                  f"#{i} {inp_str=} {inp_codes=} {postprocess_codes=}",
            )
```

But I see that the results of this two datasets are shuffled and don't match each other.
The reason is clear: after starting a new iterator operator shuffling starts again.
I can switch off full shuffling but it is rather complicated for the full pipeline.

I am thinking about some option which can freeze the dataset so that all iterations on it produce same results.

Is it possible to solve this problem this way?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple:
`cache()` function

so

```
ds = ds.take(1).cache()
```

will make all new iterators stable